# Capturing selected values from inputs into a common object

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a scenario where I want to output some select inputs based on an object containing configuration options such as placeholder text, options to use for the select, etc.

I already have this working, but I need to trap each of the selections made in a common object that I can use to build out a query string - they are being used for some filter options for a subsequent back end call.

I thought ng-model would be my friend here but I'm not so sure it will, unless there's a way for me to set some named properties on an object dynamically.

Here's my md-select markup, a working codepen can be found [here](http://codepen.io/parky128/pen/KVMgwe)

```
<md-select flex ng-model="filterBy.test" ng-repeat="filter in availableFilters" placeholder="{{filter.placeholder}}">
    <md-option ng-repeat="option in filter.data" value="{{option.value}}">
        {{option.description}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

What I'd like is to end up with an object populated from the input selections like so:

```
filterBy = {
    TimePeriodFilter: 'last24',
    OtherFilter: 2
}
```

I know what I have done so far will not work since I'm trying to use the same named ng-model property, so it just gets overwritten on each selection. Also I dont have the filter name e.g 'TimePeriodFilter' available from the selected option.

Can anyone offer some inspiration on how I could get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the select to this:

```
<md-select flex ng-model="filterBy[filter.name]" ng-repeat="filter in availableFilters" placeholder="{{filter.placeholder}}">
              <md-option ng-repeat="option in filter.data" value="{{option.value}}">
                {{option.description}}
              </md-option>
            </md-select>
```

See the ng-model.

Comment: Duhhh, how did I miss that?!! Brain fade! Thanks @Victor

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your filter model as an object in controller.

```
$scope.filterBy = {};
```

Now you can assign each property inside the `$scope.filterBy` from the view like,

```
<md-select flex ng-model="filterBy[filter.placeholder]" ng-repeat="filter in availableFilters" placeholder="{{filter.placeholder}}">

</md-select>
```

If you have any property with filter name inside your filter, you can use that property.

Answer (score 0):

Answered something similar over here  :
[Show a list of items inside an ng-repeat when an input is selected with model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128285/show-a-list-of-items-inside-an-ng-repeat-when-an-input-is-selected-with-model/42129180#42129180)

https://plnkr.co/edit/OJm07aLJQTCVgWSGgnZt?p=preview

```
    <div ng-repeat="subj in subjects track by $index">
      <label>Prerequisites for {{subj.subjectCode}}</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="multiPre[$index]" ng-click="test($index)">
  </div>
  <select ng-model="multiPre[selected]" multiple>
    <option ng-repeat="sb in subjects[selected].prerequisites">{{sb}}</option>
  </select>
```