# Show a list of items inside an ng-repeat when an input is selected with model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

So, I have this ng-repeat which has a model inside subj.Prerequisites, subj.Prerequisites can contain an array e.g ['SUBJ1', 'SUBJ2']. What i wanted to do is when i click on my input text inside this ng-repeat there will be a shown list of subjects below which allow multiple selection and then with the multiple selected items should be binded to the clicked input text.

```
<div  ng-repeat="subj in sem.subjects track by $index">
   <md-input-container flex class="no-error-spacer uk-margin-remove">
      <label>Prerequisites</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="subj.Prerequisites" ng-value="(subj.Prerequisites.length <= 0) ? null : subj.Prerequisites" readonly="true">
   </md-input-container>
</div>

<select multiple>
 <option ng-repeat="sb in subjects" value="sb.subjectCode>{{ sb.subjectCode }}</option>
</select>
```

Its kind the hard for me though. Please someone help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: show `$scope.sem.subjects`

Comment: here's an array of my sem.subjects

[
    { subjectCode: 'SUBJ1', prerequisites: ['S1','S2'] },
    { subjectCode: 'SUBJ2', prerequisites: ['S3','S4'] },
    
]

so prerequisites are loaded into inpute text with format S1,S2 and S3,S4 i could put it also into md-select which is S1,S2 are checked and S3,S4 are also checked but my problem is that if a lot of rows to repeat its kinda lag and takes a lot of time to load i use md-select with ng-repeat inside

Comment: Cool problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding of your question. Please look into this working plunker :

```
    <div ng-repeat="subj in subjects track by $index">
      <label>Prerequisites for {{subj.subjectCode}}</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="multiPre[$index]" ng-click="test($index)">
  </div>
  <select ng-model="multiPre[selected]" multiple>
    <option ng-repeat="sb in subjects[selected].prerequisites">{{sb}}</option>
  </select>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/2brsDinqAouZ9h6w1taT?p=preview

PS: I have left {{multipre}} intentionally for your understanding of model.

**Edit Start :**

Try This : 
https://plnkr.co/edit/OJm07aLJQTCVgWSGgnZt?p=preview

This addressees to your requirement.

Comment: the list should be hidden until you clicked into an input and it should be below the input. Your answer is awesome though but diff. from what i wanted

Comment: Checkout the new plunker above.